# How to Get Azure Data Factory to continue loading when error is encountered on SnowFlake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I am copying data into a SnowFlake database and I'm getting the Error from ADF

```
ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [22000] String '<div class="ExternalClassFEF297CEF4014BF7AC93A5068BA8801E"><div style="font-family&#58;Calibri, Arial' is too long and would be truncated
  File '912f8683-d5da-48ce-b009-493f9b2b39b1/SnowflakeImportCopyCommand/Commentary6ec0c04003c6aa892ecde458ae63679bc746fc7a2bed3859b1a395d4b1f80279.txt', line 2, character 0
  Row 2, column "COMMENTARY"["COMMENTARY":10]
  If you would like to continue loading when an error is encountered, use other values such as 'SKIP_FILE' or 'CONTINUE' for the ON_ERROR option. For more information on loading options, please run 'info loading_data' in a SQL client.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.GenericOdbcConnectors,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [22000] String '<div class="ExternalClassFEF297CEF4014BF7AC93A5068BA8801E"><div style="font-family&#58;Calibri, Arial' is too long and would be truncated
  File '912f8683-d5da-48ce-b009-493f9b2b39b1/SnowflakeImportCopyCommand/Commentary6ec0c04003c6aa892ecde458ae63679bc746fc7a2bed3859b1a395d4b1f80279.txt', line 2, character 0
  Row 2, column "COMMENTARY"["COMMENTARY":10]
  If you would like to continue loading when an error is encountered, use other values such as 'SKIP_FILE' or 'CONTINUE' for the ON_ERROR option. For more information on loading options, please run 'info loading_data' in a SQL client.,Source=SnowflakeODBC_sb64.dll,'
```

I think I understand the error, (it's basically letting me know that the column called 'Commentary as a string of [22000] and is too long), at least that is what I think the error is telling me.

When I copy the same data to Azure SQLDB it copies with no problems, although looks like the following:
[image]

According to the error message there is the option to continue loading when an error is encountered.

Can someone let me know how to enable that option?

I have just realised that the number 22000 is probably the error code, doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select Snowflake as a sink **additionalCopyOptions** provide you these options

**additionalCopyOptions** - Additional copy options, provided as a dictionary of key-value pairs. Examples: `ON_ERROR`, `FORCE`, `LOAD_UNCERTAIN_FILES`.

***You can set these options as below:***

[image]

Comment: Hi @Pratik, thanks for reaching out. I will try your suggestion and let you know how I get on. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Pratik, I'm going the dropdowns. Just to let you know, the 'CONTINUE' dropdown resulted in no data being copied. Going to check out a few of the other options

Comment: Continue option will let you complete the query irrespective of the error so it will not populate any error if it's occurring the data is not getting copied can be because of another issue.